# Sticky JS is not working in tablet/mobile screen

Tags: javascript, html, sticky

Hi I'm using jQuery plugin, Sticky JS to create a sticky header. It works fine for desktop but it doesn't fix properly for mobile/tablet screen.

**Ideal behaviour**

The header should fix like this, the top of the page when I scroll down.
[image]

**Current behaviour**

But the header fixes like this. Top of the header is hidden when I scroll down.
[image]

JS

```
var stickyWrapper = $(".outer-wrapper");

    stickyWrapper.sticky({
        topSpacing: 0,
        getWidthFrom: "html",
        responsiveWidth: true,
        widthFromWrapper: false,
        zIndex: 99
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper" style="height: 76px;">
    <div class="outer-wrapper">
        <div class="header-inner">
        <a class="logo" href="/">
            <div id="logo" class="svg--logo"></div>
        </a>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anybody have idea why this weird behaviour happen?

Thank you,

Comment: Does it have to be sticky from the JS? Can you not use CSS?

Comment: Yes, I want to know the reason why it happens.